# Loop through checkbox array in php to display icons

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I wish to create a property page where features/facilities are represented by icons (e.g. swimming pool, laundry, bbq, etc.).
I plan to use a checkbox array in the admin form to select the features/facilities and a foreach loop to pull the results from the db.
Where I'm stuck is how to translate the array results into displaying the relevant icons.

I apologise for lack of code but I'm at the conceptual stage and am stumpped already (not a good start I know) and wondered if any of you lovely people might have an idea of how I might get each value in the array (if present by being checked) to display the relevant icon please?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you able to retrieve the data from the DB but are having trouble actually displaying it as relevant images?

Comment: Yes.  I can get an array from the database which has been inserted via a checkbox array (e.g. [1,3] to show that checkboxes 1 and 3 are checked).  I just can't get my head around how I'll use that data to load corresponding icons or images.  Having a blank day!  Sorry.

Comment: For the record, I ended up saving the checkbox array as an imploded string in the database, then recalled it as an exploded string and used str_replace to compare against an array of chars and replace them with image tags for the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the location of the icon in the record for each feature/facility, then simply use these in `Img` tags along with your checkboxes etc

Comment: Sensational! Thank you so much.  It seems obvious now you say it but I couldn't get there by myself.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="swimming pool">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="laundry">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="bbq">
```

**PHP:**

```
foreach($_POST['options'] as $option_key => $option_name)
{
   echo $option_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this and I apologise for my lazy approach to this question. This much I knew, it was how to use the array data to reference a specific icon image that I was struggling with which has been answered below.